# JPA: How to delete link record in unidirectional many to many relationship?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have an unidirectional many to many mapping for entity 'Activity' and 'Invoice'. The mapping is set in Activity entity only( I don't need access activity from Invoice side).

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "OP_ACTIVITY_INVOICE_XREF", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ACTIVITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "OBJECT_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "INVOICE_ID", referencedColumnName = "OBJECT_ID"))
private Set<Invoice> invoices;
```

The insert and update are working fine, but I am having problem with deleting activity. The deleting activity code is as below:

```
    activity.getInvoices().clear();
    em.remove(activity);
```

when I run these code, I thought the em will delete the record from join table first, then delete activity record (invoice records should remain untouched). but the record in join table never get deleted. I am getting this foreign key error:

```
[STDOUT] Hibernate: delete from OP_ACTIVITY where OBJECT_ID=?
[JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 1451, SQLState: 23000 
ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`prod/op_activity_invoice_xref`.......
```

What am I doing wrong here? please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

<s>I think you need the `@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE})` option.</s>

> CascadeType.REMOVE: When deleting an entity, also delete the entities
>   held in this field.

In Activity :

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE})
@JoinTable(name = "OP_ACTIVITY_INVOICE_XREF", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ACTIVITY_ID",  referencedColumnName = "OBJECT_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "INVOICE_ID", referencedColumnName = "OBJECT_ID"))
private Set<Invoice> invoices;
```

Apparently REMOVE should not be used with @ManyToMany (from JPA 2.0 spec.):

> The relationship modeling annotation constrains the use of the
>   cascade=REMOVE specification. The cascade=REMOVE specification should
>   only be applied to associations that are specified as OneToOne or
>   OneToMany. Applications that apply cascade=REMOVE to other
>   associations are not portable.

You can try the vendor extension @OnDelete in Hibernate:

> @OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)

Or you can do it manually :

```
for (Invoice invoice : activity.getInvoices()) {
   em.remove(invoice);
}
activity.getInvoices().clear();
em.remove(activity);
... flush() etc...
```

Or you can the annotation @PreRemove:
Add the following method to the entity that is not the owner of the relationship (Invoice)

```
@PreRemove
private void removeInvoicesFromActivities() {
    for (Activity a : activities) {
        a.getInvoices().remove(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: tried adding cascadeType.remove option, but no difference. it doesn't remove the link record so I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it turns out my problem is related to something else. this is the correct way to remove the link record(as I said before, I don't want to delete invoice):

   `activity.getInvoices().clear();
    em.remove(activity);`